# jQuery - How to target a specific object with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm building an adjustable grid using JS/jQuery and ran into a problem trying to target a specific object using a for loop to display in each grid item.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
var proj01 = { projName: "Project 01",
               projImage: "red"
             };

var proj02 = { projName: "Project 02",
               projImage: "orange"
             };

var proj03 = { projName: "Project 03",
               projImage: "yellow"
             };

function gridItemGen(){

    for(i = 1; i <= gridColumns; i++){
        $("#grid_col_" + i + "").append("<h3>" + proj0[i].projName + "</h3>");
    }

}
```

So I've got the loop to go through each column add an ID to it and then apply a title from the appropriate object. I've tried concatenating but I'm not sure how you can concatenate within another concatenation:

```
function gridItemGen(){

    for(i = 1; i <= gridColumns; i++){
        $("#grid_col_" + i + "").append("<h3>" + proj0 + i + .projName + "</h3>");
    }

}
```

But that generates an error due to the dot from the property I want to select from the object.

Is there another way to do this or was I concatenating this wrong?

Comment: You could try referencing the variable with `window['proj0'+ i]` if the variables are global.

Comment: `proj0` doesn't exist in your code. you've got `proj01`, but that's an object, not an array.

Comment: you can find a solution with an array here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBJNrg?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

Put them in an array, and then index into it:

```
var projects = [
    { projName: "Project 01",
      projImage: "red"
    },
    { projName: "Project 02",
      projImage: "orange"
    },
    { projName: "Project 03",
      projImage: "yellow"
    }
];

function gridItemGen(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= gridColumns; i++){
        $("#grid_col_" + i + "").append("<h3>" + projects[i - 1].projName + "</h3>");
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer, a non-array object with property names:

```
var projects = {
    proj01:  { projName: "Project 01",
               projImage: "red"
             },
    proj02:  { projName: "Project 02",
               projImage: "orange"
             },
    proj03:  { projName: "Project 03",
               projImage: "yellow"
             }
};

function gridItemGen(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= gridColumns; i++){
        $("#grid_col_" + i + "").append("<h3>" + projects["proj0" + i].projName + "</h3>");
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Be sure to declare `i` within `gridItemGen`. I've added the `var` in the examples above.

Comment: Thanks @TJ, I didn't know you needed to declare the variables used in for statements. Also how come you put "[i -1]?

$("#grid_col_" + i + "").append("<h3>" + projects[i - 1].projName + "</h3>");

Would it be correct to put [i] by itself if I set "var i = 0"?

Comment: @ElecRei - The first entry in an array is at index `0`. But the loop starts with 1. So...`i-1`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select a variable name with

```
proj0 + i
```

proj0 will be considerated as a variable, and it's undefined.
the easier is to build an array instead of 3 variables :

```
var projects = [{ projName: "Project 01",
               projImage: "red"
             },

{ projName: "Project 02",
               projImage: "orange"
             },

{ projName: "Project 03",
               projImage: "yellow"
             }];
```

and then you can run this code :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        $("#grid_col_" + i + "").append("<h3>" + projects[i].projName + "</h3>");
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBJNrg?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

I agree that an array would probably make more sense, but just for argument sake, you can reference global variables off the `window`.

```js
var proj01 = {
  projName: "Project 01",
  projImage: "red"
};

var proj02 = {
  projName: "Project 02",
  projImage: "orange"
};

var proj03 = {
  projName: "Project 03",
  projImage: "yellow"
};

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(window['proj0'+ i]);
}
```